# Make pipe behave like `col('.')`

Tags: cursor-motions, tab-characters

So when I go to the first character in a line, the first character in that line is a tab character, and I execute `echo col('.')`, I will get `1`.

However when I type `2|` I won't go to the next character, but I will stay in the current position, which is because the tab character fills 8 display spaces.

So how can I make `|` behave like `col('.')` and use characters instead of display spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just barely tested. So it might still have some bugs:

```
func! Go(char)
    let ret = '/^.\{'. a:char. '}\%'. line('.'). "l/e\<cr>"
    return ret
endfunc
nnoremap <silent><expr> <leader><Bar>  Go(v:count1)
```

The idea is to search for the given number of chars in the current line.
Use the `\|` mapping to go where you want.